# Store Multiple values in a file in table format

Tags: android, text-files

I would like to store my values as a textfile and hence i used

```
try
         {
             File Mydir = new File("/sdcard/app/");
             Mydir.mkdirs();
            File outputFile = new File(Mydir, "helloworld");
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        fos.write(item1.getBytes());
        fos.write(item2.getBytes());

        // Close output stream
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();

        }
        catch (IOException ioe) 
          {
               ioe.printStackTrace();
           }
```

This is working extremely well and the values are storing properly. But now my question is i would like to store large number of values in a single file and i would like to store those values in the table format. Here the values are getting over writted one above and the last used values is only displaying. So instead of this i would like to store all the used values in a table format.

Comment: why is this writing in tabular form is so important , and if it is so importatant , write a CSV or any other such format

Comment: i would like to store all the values in a table one below the another

Comment: yeah , its just you like it that way , or there is some requirement forcing that?

Comment: If not table atleast i need those values to be stored one below the another like a listview

Comment: then whats wrong with CSV format ??

Comment: csv format is also okay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't understood the requirement of writing in tabular format but if you simply want that the new text don't overwrite the existing text in file , or simple append the new text in file , you should use

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile,true);
```

instead of

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
```

i.e.

```
try
         {
           File Mydir = new File("/sdcard/app/");
           Mydir.mkdirs();
           File outputFile = new File(Mydir, "helloworld");
           FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile, true);
           fos.write(item1.getBytes());
           fos.write(item2.getBytes());

           // Close output stream
          fos.flush();
          fos.close();

      }
    catch (IOException ioe) 
      {
           ioe.printStackTrace();
       }
```

**Edit**

For current system Date and time

```
SimpleDateFormat ft =new SimpleDateFormat ("E yyyy.MM.dd 'at' hh:mm:ss:S a zzz");
Date date= new Date();
String nowTime = ft.format(date);
```

concatenate `nowTime` with `item1` and `item2` before writing it on the file

Comment: ya this is working but can i store the same in a table with item1 in a column and item2 in a column?

Comment: @Alliswell see this answer on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740157/storing-data-in-txt-file-in-specific-format

Comment: can u pls tell me how to add system current date and time to the above code.